# set text attribute with one line code using xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using [xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) with the code 
`Element('title', text= 'KCTV')` to create element `<title>KCTV</title>`, but got `<title text="KCTV"/>` as result , so what's wrong ?

couldn't set `text` attribute with one line code using xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)?

what does the extra argument do ?

Comment: You have to be careful with the word "attribute", as that can refer to 2 things here. `extra` is for setting XML element attributes that appear as attributes in your XML element open tag. The Python object you create with Element() has got a **Python instance attribute** `text` that you can use to set the text inside your XML element. However, that text is not an XML element attribute.

Comment: @blubberdiblub (1) so the Python instance attribute text is additional data associated with the element? (2) couldn't set the Python instance attribute text with one line code using xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra), right? (3) I posted another similar question , see If you can help , thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809932/difference-between-attrib-and-extra-arguments-of-xml-etree-elementtree-eleme