# difference between `attrib` and `extra` arguments of xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Both `attrib` and `extra` arguments of [xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) could be used to set element attributes, except `attrib` should be given as a dictionary and  `extra`  given as keyword arguments, they nearly have the same effect , for example ,

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import *
>>> tostring(Element('ref', attrib={'text1': 'KCTV'}), 'utf-8')
b'<ref text1="KCTV" />'
>>> tostring(Element('ref',text1= 'KCTV'), 'utf-8')
b'<ref text1="KCTV" />'
>>>
```

I don't see any difference between the two, (1) any difference ? (2) what's each of the argument used for ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source, they're merged together:

```
attrib.update(extra)
```

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l172

It's been there since ElementTree was a third party library supporting Python 1.5.2.

One would imagine that it's there for convenience, since it may be quite common to have a dictionary of attributes from somewhere, but it should also be ergonomic to write a literal function call with some attribute names, so neither case requires extra punctuation.